# Removing objects from an array based on another array

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode

I have two arrays like this:

```
var arrayA = ["Mike", "James", "Stacey", "Steve"]
var arrayB = ["Steve", "Gemma", "James", "Lucy"]
```

As you can see, `James` and `Steve` match and I want to be able to remove them from `arrayA`. How would I write this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Like this:

```
var arrayA = ["Mike", "James", "Stacey", "Steve"]
var arrayB = ["Steve", "Gemma", "James", "Lucy"]
for word in arrayB {
    if let ix = find(arrayA, word) {
        arrayA.removeAtIndex(ix)
    }
}
// now arrayA is ["Mike", "Stacey"]
```

Comment: This solution works pretty well for small arrays, but it must be kept into account that its complexity is O(n^2). For larger arrays I would consider converting `arrayA` into a set and using it for the `find` - that should reduce complexity to O(2n)

Answer (score 74):

@francesco-vadicamo's answer in **Swift 2/3/4+**

```
 arrayA = arrayA.filter { !arrayB.contains($0) }
```

Comment: Should still turn `arrayB` into a `Set` first.

Comment: @BallpointBen I've added a demo link on the answer: as you can see, it works as expected.

Comment: @cleexiang there’s a demo in my answer, you can run it with Swift 4 :)

Comment: Have you? I just did in Xcode 9.2 (and previously in 9.0) and it works. If it doesn't for you, please show some code and I'll try to help.

Answer (score 40):

The easiest way is by using the new `Set` container (added in Swift 1.2 / Xcode 6.3):

```
var setA = Set(arrayA)
var setB = Set(arrayB)

// Return a set with all values contained in both A and B
let intersection = setA.intersect(setB) 

// Return a set with all values in A which are not contained in B
let diff = setA.subtract(setB)
```

If you want to reassign the resulting set to `arrayA`, simply create a new instance using the copy constructor and assign it to `arrayA`:

```
arrayA = Array(intersection)
```

The downside is that you have to create 2 new data sets.
Note that `intersect` doesn't mutate the instance it is invoked in, it just returns a new set.

There are similar methods to add, subtract, etc., you can take a look at them

Comment: Sorry I've never used Set before. I've just dropped it into playground and it's saying: `Use of unresolved identifier 'Set'`. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: Forgot to mention that it's available in Swift 1.2 - I presume you're not using Xcode 6.3

Comment: Ahh Ok, You assume right, I'll update tonight and give it a go. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry I've just realised, this actually does the opposite of what I want to do, I want to take the match names away, not be left with them? Can this be done with a similar process?

Comment: @HenryBrown Yeah my mistake - you should use `substract`, see udpated answer. Take also a look at the [documentation](http://swiftdoc.org/type/Set/) if you need to know more - there are other useful methods.

Comment: Converting to Set and back might change the order of the elements, so if you care about order you should not use this.

Comment: This is useless for duplicate values.

Comment: I found this to be the best answer ever. Look at the code. Intersect and subtract of sets are much more efficient than iterating through EVERY item. Plus, Apple recommends that, as an easier solution. Just read the Swift Language guide: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html

Answer (score 13):

I agree with Antonio's answer, however for small array subtractions you can also use a filter closure like this:

```
let res = arrayA.filter { !contains(arrayB, $0) }
```

Comment: This is nice because it preserves ordering

Comment: arrayA = arrayA.filter { !arrayB.contains($0) } => works, above NOT work

Answer (score 12):

matt and freytag's solutions are the ONLY ones that account for duplicates and should be receiving more +1s than the other answers.

Here is an updated version of matt's answer for Swift 3.0:

```
var arrayA = ["Mike", "James", "Stacey", "Steve"]
var arrayB = ["Steve", "Gemma", "James", "Lucy"]
for word in arrayB {
    if let ix = arrayA.index(of: word) {
        arrayA.remove(at: ix)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

**Original answer**

This can also be implemented as a minus func:

```
func -<T:RangeReplaceableCollectionType where T.Generator.Element:Equatable>( lhs:T, rhs:T ) -> T {

    var lhs = lhs
    for element in rhs {
        if let index = lhs.indexOf(element) { lhs.removeAtIndex(index) }
    }

    return lhs
}
```

Now you can use

```
arrayA - arrayB
```

---

**Updated implementation for Swift 5**

```swift
func -<T: RangeReplaceableCollection>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> T where T.Iterator.Element: Equatable {

    var lhs = lhs
    for element in rhs {
        if let index = lhs.firstIndex(of: element) { lhs.remove(at: index) }
    }

    return lhs
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Using the `Array → Set → Array` method mentioned by Antonio, and with the convenience of an operator, as freytag pointed out, I've been very satisfied using this:

```
// Swift 3.x/4.x
func - <Element: Hashable>(lhs: [Element], rhs: [Element]) -> [Element]
{
    return Array(Set<Element>(lhs).subtracting(Set<Element>(rhs)))
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For smaller arrays I use:

```
/* poormans sub for Arrays */

extension Array where Element: Equatable {

    static func -=(lhs: inout Array, rhs: Array) {

        rhs.forEach {
            if let indexOfhit = lhs.firstIndex(of: $0) {
                lhs.remove(at: indexOfhit)
            }
        }
    }

    static func -(lhs: Array, rhs: Array) -> Array {

        return lhs.filter { return !rhs.contains($0) }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Remove elements using indexes array:**

1. Array of Strings and indexes

   ```
   let animals = ["cats", "dogs", "chimps", "moose", "squarrel", "cow"]
   let indexAnimals = [0, 3, 4]
   let arrayRemainingAnimals = animals
       .enumerated()
       .filter { !indexAnimals.contains($0.offset) }
       .map { $0.element }

   print(arrayRemainingAnimals)

   //result - ["dogs", "chimps", "cow"]
   ```
2. Array of Integers and indexes

   ```
   var numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
   let indexesToRemove = [3, 5, 8, 12]

   numbers = numbers
       .enumerated()
       .filter { !indexesToRemove.contains($0.offset) }
       .map { $0.element }

   print(numbers)

   //result - [0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11]
   ```

**Remove elements using element value of another array**

3. Arrays of integers

   ```
   let arrayResult = numbers.filter { element in
       return !indexesToRemove.contains(element)
   }
   print(arrayResult)

   //result - [0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11]
   ```
4. Arrays of strings

   ```
   let arrayLetters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"]
   let arrayRemoveLetters = ["a", "e", "g", "h"]
   let arrayRemainingLetters = arrayLetters.filter {
       !arrayRemoveLetters.contains($0)
   }

   print(arrayRemainingLetters)

   //result - ["b", "c", "d", "f", "i"]
   ```