# Swift 3 Remove objects from an array that are present in another array using set and maintaining order

Tags: arrays, swift

```
Array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

Array2 = [1,5]
```

I want to get:

```
Array1 = [2, 3, 4, 6]
```

I want to do this by using `Set` because these arrays may get larger.
Also it is important that I maintain the order of the array.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42679608/1930509

Comment: I can not understand exactly how to implement that answer to my arrays can you show how

Comment: see answer below

Comment: note: use lowercased varialble names to avoid confusion with Class names

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Create a *set* with all elements from the second array, 
then *filter* the first array to get only the elements which are *not*
in the set:

```
let array1 = [5, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2]
let array2 = [1, 5]

let set2 = Set(array2)
let result = array1.filter { !set2.contains($0) }

print(result) // [4, 2, 3, 4, 2]
```

This preserves the order (and duplicate elements) from the first
array. Using a set is advantageous if the second array can be large,
because the lookup is faster.

Comment: OutStanding Working for me

Answer (score 3):

```
var array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

var array2 = [1,5]

var arrayResult = array1.enumerated()
    .filter { !array2.contains($0.0 + 1) }
    .map { $0.1 }

print(arrayResult)
```

> [2, 3, 4, 6]

Another ways to achieve the same result:

**1. User filter**

```
let arrayResult = array1.filter { element in
    return !array2.contains(element)
}
```

**2. Use Sort**

```
array2.sorted(by: >).forEach { if $0 < self.array1.count { self.array1.remove(at: $0) } }
```

**Remove elements using indexes array:**

1. Array of Strings and indexes

   ```
   let animals = ["cats", "dogs", "chimps", "moose", "squarrel", "cow"]
   let indexAnimals = [0, 3, 4]
   let arrayRemainingAnimals = animals
       .enumerated()
       .filter { !indexAnimals.contains($0.offset) }
       .map { $0.element }

   print(arrayRemainingAnimals)

   //result - ["dogs", "chimps", "cow"]
   ```
2. Array of Integers and indexes

   ```
   var numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
   let indexesToRemove = [3, 5, 8, 12]

   numbers = numbers
       .enumerated()
       .filter { !indexesToRemove.contains($0.offset) }
       .map { $0.element }

   print(numbers)

   //result - [0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11]
   ```

**Remove elements using element value of another array**

3. Arrays of integers

   ```
   let arrayResult = numbers.filter { element in
       return !indexesToRemove.contains(element)
   }
   print(arrayResult)

   //result - [0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11]
   ```
4. Arrays of strings

   ```
   let arrayLetters = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"]
   let arrayRemoveLetters = ["a", "e", "g", "h"]
   let arrayRemainingLetters = arrayLetters.filter {
       !arrayRemoveLetters.contains($0)
   }

   print(arrayRemainingLetters)

   //result - ["b", "c", "d", "f", "i"]
   ```

Comment: This works, but I honestly think using a dictionary is a cleaner method. Would you agree with me? @Krunal

Comment: Yes, agree with you

Comment: please: use lowercased variabel names to distinct from Class names

Answer (score 1):

Use the filter function

```
let result = Array1.filter { element in
    return !Array2.contains(element)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*(Note: because you added to your question `and maintaining order` then my answer is not right anymore, because `Set` don't preserve the order. then the `filter` answers are a better fit)*

use `subtracting` from a `Set`:

```
array1 = Array(Set(array1).subtracting(Set(array2)))
```

you can add this as an operator :

> Using the Array → Set → Array method mentioned by Antonio, and with the convenience of an operator, as freytag pointed out, I've been very satisfied using this:
>
> ```
> // Swift 3.x
>
> func - <Element: Hashable>(lhs: [Element], rhs: [Element]) -> [Element]
> {
>     return Array(Set<Element>(lhs).subtracting(Set<Element>(rhs)))
> }
> ```

quoted from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42679608/1930509

Comment: can you show how you would use the operator and subtracting together I am still a little confused

Comment: Sets are unordered collections.  This isn't guaranteed to maintain the order of the original items.

Comment: thx, yes i know - but he changed his original question later and added  `and maintaining order`. i added a note to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
let array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
let array2 = [1,5]

let array3 = array1.reduce([]) { array2.contains($1) ? $0 : $0 + [$1] } 

print(array3)  // "[2, 3, 4, 6]\n"
```